# Bookshelf relation with through and custom key columns

Tags: bookshelf.js

This is my relation chain.

```
applications.applicant_id -> users.id -> skills_users.user_id
                                         skills_users.id <- ratings.rateable_id
```

I want get an `Application` with a custom relation `applicant_skills`, and preferably join in `ratings`. So I was hoping something like this would work:

```
applicant_ratings: function () {
  return this.belongsToMany('SkillUser').through('User')
},
```

But I cannot get it to work. I have tried different combinations of "key"-parameters, but none seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `'users'` is not a pivot, but `'skills_users'` is. More like:

```
applications.applicant_id -> users.id <- skills_users.user_id
                                         skills_users.id <- ratings.rateable_id
```

Try perhaps:

```
var Application = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'applications',
    applicant_ratings: function () {
        return this.belongsTo('User', 'applicant_id')
            .hasMany('Rating')
            .through('SkillUser','rateable_id');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. It generates a query with `where "skills_users"."user_id" in (?)` with `application.id` as the binding, which is wrong. It should bind `application.applicant_id`.